# What is wrong with this map?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I am a bit puzzled, why the following code is not working as expected...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Foo {
    int x,y,z;
    Foo(int x,int y,int z) : x(x),y(y),z(z) {}
    bool operator<(const Foo& other) const {
       if (x > other.x) return false;
       if (y > other.y) return false;
       if (z > other.z) return false;
       return true;
    }
    bool operator==(const Foo& other) const {
        if (other.x != x) return false;
        if (other.y != y) return false;
        if (other.z != z) return false;
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f(1,2,3);
    std::map<Foo,double> map;
    map[f] = 1.0;
    std::cout << map[f] << "\n";
}
```

It prints `0` and not `1`. What did I do wrong?

code also here: http://ideone.com/fork/HMwPQ7

Comment: Your inversion of key/value in MyMap template argument is _evil_!

Comment: @YSC as is the non-throwing `at` function... Minefield code, that's what this snippet is!

Comment: @YSC as the answers didnt refer to that evilness, I allowed myself to edit it out. It was a left over from the real code, where `key` is a parameter pack, so I didnt know any better than to reverse the order of key/value

Comment: @Quentin To be honest I dont really know what was wrong with that `at`. I am really ignorant when it comes to exceptions :(. Should it look like this `V& at(const K& k) { try { return map[k]; } catch (...) { throw; }  }` (first thing I found after a quick search) ? Well, obviously not, but how could it be fixed?

Comment: @tobi303 when the queried key does not exist in an `std::map`, its `operator []` will add it with a default value, while its `at()` will throw an exception. Hence my first thought reading your code was "zero? What? that `at()` should blow up on an empty map...". So unless your custom map grows sufficiently different from an `std::map` that the confusion is avoided, you should really mimic its interface by forwarding `[]` to `[]` and `at()` to `at()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Foo::operator <` does not define the [strict weak ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) required by `std::map`.
In particular, given two identical `Foo`s `a` and `b`, both `a < b` and `b < a` are true, when they should both be false.
Since you broke `std::map`'s contract, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @Dan it will? I have to try that :) / Edit: `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` doesn't cut it. Is this about MSVC's STL?

Comment: I think it is "strict *weak* ordering, not just "strict ordering".

Comment: Nawaz's answer is prettier and proposes solutions nicely, but this is the only one to directly explain the problem. Between the two of you, good job.

Answer (score 8):

It is because your `operator<` has been implemented incorrectly. Here is the correct version:

```
bool operator<(const Foo& other) const {
   if (x != other.x) return x < other.x;
   else if (y != other.y) return y < other.y;
   return z < other.z;
}
```

That basically says if `x` are equal, then compare `y`, if that too equals, then compare `z`.

Read about [Strict Weak Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

A shorter implementation could be this:

```
bool operator<(const Foo& other) const {
   return std::tie(x, y,z) < std::tie(other.x, other.y, other.z);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Dan: `std::tie` is just a friendly-function to create an instance of std::tuple of *references* (i.e without making copies).

Comment: FYI, replacing `>` with `>=` in the `operator<` impl does the trick too.

Comment: @YSC: You can see the problem just by looking at the implementation because if `x` are equals, that basically means you need to compare `y`, but you dont do that, you instead `return false` which is wrong. Your test-case does not catch that. Now see this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f64c50d5c8afc906 ..

Comment: ... and then see this (with fix): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e2f5a9d3efe9f8b